# How do I set up a recurring payment option without an SSL certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, paypal, payment

I have a Ruby on Rails site where users don't have any private data, so I don't yet have an SSL certificate. (Also, the free tier of Cloudflare doesn't work with HTTPS). However, I want to allow users to pay for membership on the site. How can I setup a simple recurring payment option on the site? Can I direct users to Paypal and it will provide my app with the necessary information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal actually has a Website Payments Basic option that can do this. It's hosted on Paypal's site so it falls under their SSL

https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring

Comment: Thanks. Do they also return information to the website so it can upgrade t he user's account?

Comment: Yeah. Data will be sent back to you via IPN https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/